# Using the if "x" in function to do a calculator but total isn't being produced

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python and I'm having trouble with my code, I'm using the if in function to do a calculator of a greengrocer and when typing three apples are being bought the total is being produced as £0 when it should be £3.90

```
total = 0


print "Welcome to the green grocers, what would you like?"
print "1. Apples"
print "2: Bananas"
print "3. Oranges"
print "4. Total"



fruit = raw_input("What would you like?")

if "1" in fruit:
   q = input("How many?")
   total + (q*1.3)
   fruit = raw_input("What would you like?")

if "2" in fruit:
   g = input("How many?")
   total + (g*1.5)
   fruit = raw_input("What would you like?")

if "3" in fruit:
   l = input("How many?")
   total = (l*1.6)
   fruit = raw_input("What would you like?")

   if "4" in fruit:
   print "Your total is £", total
```

Comment: You also need to put an indented code block under `if "4" in fruit:` or dedent that line.

Comment: Why someone downvoted this? He said he's a newbie. And the question is well redacted. I don't see why should be downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

```
total = total + (q*1.3)
```

or:

```
total += (q*1.3)
```

Integers are immutable, just doing `total + (q*1.3)` is not going to affect `total`, it simply returns a new integer.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x + 2   # Simply returns a new value, doesn't affects `x`
3
>>> x       # `x` is still unchanged
1
>>> x += 1  # Assign the new value back to `x`
>>> x       # `x` is now updated.
2
```

Answer (score 3):

You are performing the calculation but not updating the `total` variable. Do it like this:

```
total = total + (g*1.5)
```

or with the `+=` operator:

```
total += g*15
```

Hope this helps!